# Liferay template get profile picture

Tags: liferay, freemarker

Hello i'm using Freemarker and i have to get the profile picture of user, i have the object user with the portraitId, but i don't know how get Theme Display for get the path or something... I've tried use this:

```
src="/image/user_male_portrait?img_id=${user.getPortraitId()}&img_id_token="
```

But i can't get the token, because i don't know :(

```
<#assign UserLocalService = serviceLocator.findService("com.liferay.portal.service.UserLocalService")>
<#assign user = UserLocalService.getUserById(27132)>
```

Someone know how get profile picture in freemarker?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141823

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the `themeDisplay` object already exists in liferay freemarker. So you can just call it as is.

Also the `user` object also has a method `getPortraitUrl()` that you can call to get the user's image directly.

Answer (score 1):

You can retrive the user by doing

```
<#assign user = themeDisplay.getUser() />
```

and then display the profile picture (aka portrait in Liferay, but commonly called avatar) like this

```
<img src="${user.getPortraitURL(themeDisplay)}">
```